# DICOM multi-frame image with both gray scale and color frames

Tags: dicom

I need to write some code to export an multi-frame image that contains both grayscale and color frames. I'm very new to DICOM so still trying to figure things out. I see there are multi-frame grayscale and multi-frame color SOP classes but not sure how to mix the two. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of that export? And why is it a requirement to use the same color model in all exported files/frames?

Comment: Hi!,What have you tried and what is not working you need to explain with code. Please take some time to read the help page, [How To Ask Good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . SO is not a free code delivery community. What have you tried and what is not working you need to explain with code.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you would need to convert all frames into a single color space (called Photometric Interpretation in DICOM). Most probably, you want to convert the grayscale frames into color images.

Depending on the type of images, you might also think about the "PALETTE COLOR" model, blending two images or...